# PGP disk passphrase not recognized

Tags: encryption, pgp, disk-encryption

I have an external drive fully encrypted with Symantec encryption desktop software using a pgp key.
It has been done 15 years ago.
Today I try to access the disk, but it's not working. It doesn't recognized the passphrase. I'm 100% sure of the passphrase.
Since I made encryption using private key, my primary mail has changed.
On the soft, there is a question mark on the right of the mail address. What does it mean?
[image]

How to get access my data back?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the PGP passphrase contain any characters besides alpha-numeric characters? In the last 15 years UTF-8 encoding has become the default string encoding, before often platform specific encodings were used.

Comment: Are you using an old backup of the private key? The passphrase is used to unlock the PGP key – not the disk itself – so different copies of the same PGP key may have different passphrases, e.g. if you've exported it to a backup file years ago and then changed the passphrase and exported it again.

Comment: Hi,

I used the same passphrase since I have created it, no special characters.
I have added the @wanadoo.fr in the key, but it is signed with new mail (the primary one). Still not working.

Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of the blue question mark in the User access section on the left of the mail address?

Comment: Make sure that your keyboard is set up with the correct keyboard layout. I've had it happen that the keyboard layout was wrong, so while I was using the correct key on the keyboard, the mapping was different, and my passphrase would never be correct.

Comment: I have checked 'show keystrokes' to be sure.

Comment: I'm able to change my passphrase on my private key. The mapping of the keyboard is correct. It looks like I've encrypted the drive using my private key with a different main email address. Since I changed my main mail address, the old one looks not recognized. Maybe that's why there is a blue question mark on the left of the mail address as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: I finally access to my drive. I have imported old backup key, which has the address '@wanadoo.fr' in the list of mails attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally access to my drive. I have imported old backup key, which has the address '@wanadoo.fr' in the list of mails attached to it.